# Windows Phone cant create a switch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

When i try to run emulator for windows phone 8.1 in the visual studio 2013 i get this error and I cant find out what is going on
http://wrzucaj.net/gVt

The first sentense means something like "Error occurred while creating virtual switch ethernet network"

And the second one:
"Making the switch failed"

What should i do? 
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone emulator is a Virtual machine running under HyperV. The error means the HyperV isn't able to create the a netswithc for the emulator. Open the Hyper-V Manager from the start menu, and open the Virtual Switch Manager. Remove any existing switches, and try make a new virtual switch with a connection type set to internal.

You might need to run XdeCleanup.exe afterwards.

Comment: When i try to add new virtual switch in the virtual switch mengaer i get an error "Making the switch failed" and when i write "XdeCleanup.exe" in the command line its not found

Comment: There are some posts on Technet covering this problem. Google show them after the search for "hyperv Making the switch failed"